# Heroku billing paid by a third party?

Tags: heroku

I've been working on a project for a few months, running on a free dyno. It is now time to move to production. The company insists on paying directly for the hosting (instead of paying me and letting me handle payments to heroku), however I can't find any option to pay for the service from a third party.

I haven't asked, but I doubt they want to link their credit card to my heroku account.

If it matters, we will use a hobby dyno and the cheapest version of the PostgreSQL addon (not the free version), as it is a small system with 20 users.

Is the only way to solve this to create a separate account just for this company? Or am I missing some option?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the company want to have their own heroku account and not letting you have the credit card or something else.

About heroku and third party billing, i think it's not possible

Comment: They don't have an IT department (I'm actually slowly becoming the IT department) so I thought it would be unnecessary to have a whole new account just for the one app that I will manage alone. It seems like it is the best solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up a [team](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-teams), you can set a credit card on it, different from your main account's card.
Then, your client pays for usage for that team and you retain your own account.

Comment: This looks perfect! Will try it out today.